# Is this the right way to use search and replace function for 2 or more matches?

Tags: python

```
s = 'this,,,is,,,good,a'

s = re.sub(r",{2,}", ",", s)

s = 'this,is,good,a'
```

If the text has 2 or more commas, I want to delete all but keep one. This seems to work fine. Is there any potential flaw?

Comment: I think this is correct.

Comment: Yes, this works for all test cases

Comment: If I also want to remove all spaces but keep one, the pattern should be r"[,s]{2,}"?